# Bootstrap on homepage full image

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have this:

_Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - LolaBikeMen</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>



    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    @*<span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>*@
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>



                @Html.ActionLink("LolaBikeMen", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <br />


                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>*@
                        <li class="nav ">@Html.ActionLink("WHO", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li class="nav ">@Html.ActionLink("WHAT", "Index", "Student")</li>
                        <li class="nav ">@Html.ActionLink("AGENDA", "Index", "Course")</li>
                        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("PHILOSPY", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
                        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("BUCKET-LIST", "Index", "Department")</li>
                        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("LolaRiders", "Index", "LolaBiker")</li>
                        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("bycicle", "Index", "Bycicle")</li>

                       @*<li class="nav"> @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")</li>*@

                    </ul>



            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    @*<li class="nav"><img src="~/Images/LolabikesCoffeeLogo3.jpg"> </li>*@
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()

        @*<footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - LolaBikeMen</p>
        </footer>*@
    </div>

    @*<div class="fill">


    </div>*@

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Cyborg-bootstrap.min")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
.container{
    /*background-color:MenuText;*/
}
.container2{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

html {
            background: url(~/Images/Large.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

.wrapper {
  background-image: url(../Images/Large.JPG);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.wide {
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background-image:url('../Images/Large.JPG');
  background-size:cover;
}

.wide img {
  width:100%;
}

navbar{
    color:white;
}

.table-striped>tr>td:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tr>td:nth-child(odd)>td {
    background-color:white;
}

.table.table-condensed tr th {
   border-top: 1px solid white; 
}

.table.table-condensed tr th {
   border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
}

.a:hover, a:focus {
        color:floralwhite;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

a {
    color:floralwhite;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.table.table-condensed tr td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* Change the color you want to set */
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

img {
    background-image: url('../Images/Large.JPG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/**/
#map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

#map img {
        max-width: 100%;
}

html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

.fullscreen,
.content-a {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.background {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /* custom background-position */
    background-position:50% 50%;
    /* ie8- graceful degradation */
    background-position:50% 50%\9 !important;
}

.fill {
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position:relative;
    /*overflow-x;*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
.fill{width:100%;height:100%;background-position:center;background-size:cover;}

.navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Demo */
#map { background:black; }




/**/

/* Wrapping element 
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;


}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"] {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .body-content {
        padding: 0;

    }
}
```

And INdex.cshtml(home page):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";


}

<div class="container2 fill">
    <div id="map">
        <img src="~/Images/VeryLarge.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
</div>

<!--1st Large Banner Image -->
@*<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="~/Images/Large.JPG" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @*<h1 id="text">Hello World!</h1>*@


@*<div class="jumbotron hidden-sm" >
        <img src="~/Images/IMG_4954 - Copy.JPG">
    </div>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel();
</script>
```

So on the homepage I have one big image. But it doesn't full the hole width. And also the height is not filling the whole screen. And I want that if you make the screen smaller that then the image will crop - so dependent of the dimensions of the screen. In the rest of the pages I don't want to use the whole width. So I cant leave this out this out on the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="container">
        @RenderBody()

        @*<footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - LolaBikeMen</p>
        </footer>*@
    </div>
```

Thank you

oke, I added this: to the site.css:

```
.background {
   background: url(../Images/Large.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

but how will the Index.cshtml page look like then?

like this:

```
<div class="background">

</div>
```

And if I hover my mouse on this line:

```
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
```

I get this message:

Warning 87  Validation (WE): "-webkit-background-size" is not a valid vendor specific property or it may have been deprecated.  G:\Mijn Documents\My Web Sites\Lolabikes\C#\ContosoUniversity\Content\full-width-pics.css   14  5   Lolabike

oke, I have it now like this:

Site.css:

```
body {

    background-image: url('../Images/Large.JPG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;background-size: 100%;
    /*padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;*/

}
```

and index.cshtml:

```
<div class="container fill">
    <div id="map">

    </div>
</div>
```

oke, but it is now working on all the pages :(

And not only on the homepage. The large image has to be only seen on the home page not on the other pages.

Thank you

and if I do it like this:

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
.container{
    /*background-color:MenuText;*/
}
.container2{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {


    /*padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;*/

}

/*html {
            background: url(~/Images/Large.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }*/

.wrapper {
  background-image: url(../Images/Large.JPG);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.wide {
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background-image:url('../Images/Large.JPG');
  background-size:cover;
}

.wide img {
  width:100%;
}

navbar{
    color:white;
}

.table-striped>tr>td:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tr>td:nth-child(odd)>td {
    background-color:white;
}

.table.table-condensed tr th {
   border-top: 1px solid white; 
}

.table.table-condensed tr th {
   border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
}

.a:hover, a:focus {
        color:floralwhite;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

a {
    color:floralwhite;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.table.table-condensed tr td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* Change the color you want to set */
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

img {
    background-image: url('../Images/Large.JPG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/**/
#map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

#map img {
        max-width: 100%;
}

html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

.fullscreen,
.content-a {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}


.background {
    background-image: url('../Images/Large.JPG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;

}

.fill {
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position:relative;
    /*overflow-x;*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
.fill{width:100%;height:100%;background-position:center;background-size:cover;}

.navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Demo */
#map { background:black; }




/**/

/* Wrapping element 
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;


}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"] {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .body-content {
        padding: 0;

    }
}
```

and in the index.cshtml:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

and I look in chrome(F12):

```
Remote Address:::1:41787
Request URL:http://localhost:41787/Images/Large.JPG
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

but the image is not dis-playing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
  background: url(../Images/Large.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

EDIT

Here is a alternative -

```
body { 
    background-image: url(../Images/Large.JPG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Neutrion thank you for your answare, did you read my edit?

Comment: ? Anybody some help? Thank you

Comment: Anybody? How can that be?

Comment: I am not sure what error are you facing exactly because the solutions work for me. Try answering some questions and see if you can get 50 reputation, so that you can add a bounty to this question to receive more attention.

Comment: Wait. First try a absolute link like this and see if it works and then try the relative one - http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/android-for-wallpaper-8.png

Comment: But what is the link you sent me? I can open the link. ok and can you  show me how it works by you? especially the index page. Because Body works, but then on all pages(what not has to be) I'v written that above

Comment: But can you show me how you have the Index.cshtml. Thank you

Comment: Neutrino, what is your email? Then I can sent you the project. Niels